# Time-dependent information: showing one rate and applying another

Tags: database, transactions, currency, rate

I have a situation where some information is valid only for a limited period of time.

One example is conversion rates stored in DB with **validFrom** and **ValidTo** timestamps.

Imagine the situation when user starts the process and I render a pre-receipt for him with one conversion rate, but when he finally hits the button other rate is already valid.

Some solutions I see for now:

1. Show user a message about new rate, render updated pre-receipt and ask him to submit form again.
2. To have overlaying periods of rates. So the transactions started with one rate could finish, but the new ones will start with the new rate.

While the 1st solution seems most logical, I've never seen such messages on websites. I wonder are there other solutions and what is the best practice.

Answer (score 1):

So this is a question best posed to the product owner of your application.  If I were wearing my product owner hat, I would want that the data being displayed never be out of sync, such that option (2) above never occurs.  This is to make sure the display is fair in all respects.

Ways to handle this:

1. As you say: display an alert that something changed and allow a refresh.
2. handle updates to the data tables using DHTML/ AJAX updates so that the data is usually fresh.

To summarize: it's a business decision, but generally speaking it's a bad choice to show unfair and/or out of data data on a page.